# How do I convert the weight of a product into an equivalent number of boxes in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am developing a spreadsheet to manage inventory. I have a product that is delivered to me in cases; each case has 10 boxes and each box weighs 2.5 lbs. Our scales weigh in ounces, so I need to convert the ounces into pounds, then convert the pounds into equivalent boxes to combine that number with the number of unopened boxes and combine that with unopened cases. for total product on hand by the case.

Example: I have 1 lbs. 4 oz. of opened product, which is really 1.25 lbs. or .5 of a box or .05 of a case. This value is to be added to another cell of say 5 boxes for a total of .55 cases on hand in the final cell.

How do I develop something like this

Comment: Does your scale read 20 oz, or 1lb 4oz?

Answer (score 0):

A box is 40 ounces, case is 400 ounces, and you're done. You can convert to pounds but there's no reason to do so for the goal you state. Weigh in ounces, as your scales do, and divide by 400.

```
D1 =A1/400+B1/10+C1
```

Where A is ounces, B is boxes, C is cases and D is total cases on hand.

If your scales weigh in pounds and ounces rather than just ounces, just enter them in two different cells and do the math on those:

```
E1 =A1/25+B1/400+C1/10+D1
```

Where A is pounds, B is ounces, C is boxes, D is cases and E is total cases on hand.

Comment: That is the way that it is set up now I am trying to make this process quicker and lower the human error factor.